# How to solve this django query problem without using the for loop?

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I have a query containing a list of submissions by users. Models are below, but here's the gist:

1. Each submission belongs to one problem that user tried to solve.
2. However, user can make as many submission as they want for a single problem.
3. There are several problems.
4. submissions are ordered by time of creation (descending)

I need to get a  list of all the ***final*** submissions by users. final submission is the last submission of user for a specific problem. Naturally, if user solves several problems then they would have as many final submissions.

How can I get this? Here is what I got so far but I dont know how to go on:

```
def list_final_submissions(contest_id):
    all_users = list_users(contest_id) #query of all users in contest
    problems = list_problems(contest_id) #query of all problems in contest
    final_submissions = Submission.objects.none()
    for user in all_users:
        for problem in problems:
            query = list_problem_user_submissions(contest_id, user.id, problem.id)[:1]
            if query.exists():
                final_submissions.union(query)
```

This doesnt work, but I also cant think of anything without a for loop. Is there a way to remove that loop and do it straight in query?

---

Here are the models:

`**User**: default django user model`

**Contest**:

```
class Contest(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    holder = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    start_time = models.DateTimeField()
    finish_time = models.DateTimeField()
    is_monetary = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    price = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    problems = models.ManyToManyField(Problem)
    authors = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='authors')
    participants = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='participants')
```

**Problem**:

```
class Problem(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    description=models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    writer=models.ForeignKey(user,on_delete=CASCADE)
    score=models.PositiveIntegerField(default=100)
```

**Submission**:

```
class Submission(models.Model):
    submitted_time=models.DateTimeField()
    participant=models.ForeignKey(user,on_delete=CASCADE, related_name="submissions")
    problem=models.ForeignKey(Problem,on_delete=CASCADE, related_name="submissions")
    code=models.URLField(max_length=200)
    score=models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
```

Comment: As you mentioned "final submission is the last submission" and "all the submissions are ordered in descending order" -> So, do you need to get the latest submission by the user for a particular problem?

Comment: @KapilSharma no, I need a list of  *all* of last submissions by all users for all problems.  I know how to get it for one specific user and one specific problem, its having the list of all that I cant